# Migrating from Asp.Net Webforms to Aurelia

Tags: asp.net, webforms, aurelia, migrate

I've inherited an Asp.Net webapplication using webform, and are trying to find out how to best migrate this to a more modern architecture.

I've decided to use Asp.Net Core for my new backend (moving existing logic into this new Asp.Net Core project), and I'd really like using Aurelia for my client-side logic/views.

What I'd like to do is to replace existing functionality "one-by-one" with Aurelia components communicating with the new backend.

The problem is how to bootstrap the application without Aurelia "forcing" app.html to be the initial page.

I'd like to keep the current startup page, site structure and routing, and just develop components in Aurelia that I can add to the existing webform pages.

I'm totally new to Aurelia, so please be gentle if there is an obvious answer to my question.  ;-)

Regards,
Jon S.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a member of the Aurelia Community, I was able to locate this in the docs:
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/8

...which is exactly what I was looking for!